# highstock range selector changes series data

Tags: highcharts, series

I have created a Highstock chart, in the series I have stored a new value to show that in the tooltip. 
I create dynamic data array:

```
dataArr = {
             x: val[i].month,//val is the data coming from web service
              y: val[i].value,
               orgval: val[i].orgval
            };
```

This is the data which is developed

e.g: `dataArr: [ [x: 'January', y: 29.9,orgval:'Jan -01'],
                [x: 'February', y: 71.5,orgval: 'Feb-01'],
                [x: 'March',y: 106.4,orgval: 'Mar -01']]`

I want to show the third value for eg: "**Jan -01**" in the tooltip. Initially when i load the chart the third value for eg: "**Jan -01**" is seen in the tooltip and also in the series.
But when I click the "All" button in the range selector the third value for eg: "**Jan -01**" is undefined and it is also not present in the Series.

Comment: I found that this issue happens when we change the size of Highstock chart.

Comment: Please replicate your example as live demo on jsfiddle.net

Comment: This is link of fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/2gtpA/124/) . Here in the series I have "orgval" which i want to show in the tooltip. I have consoled the series object but there no where I can see the orgval.

Comment: You need to use object instead of array and then in tooltip refer to this.point.options.orval. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2gtpA/126/

Comment: @SebastianBochan Hello Sebastian, I am using array of objects.Initially when I load the chart i can see the **orgval**, but when i select the "all" button from range selector i see the **orgval** as undefined and it is also not present in the **this.point**

Comment: This is related with fact that in ALL datagrouping works, so custom parameters are skipped. I advice you to disable [datagrouping](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.enabled) but then performance can dicrease.

Comment: Thank you @Sebastian. Yes, by removing the datagrouping the issue is solved. But the in the chart the first and the last column are seen half.

Comment: Have you tried to set a [pointRange](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointRange) param?

Comment: @Sebastian  I have set the point range then to my first and last column are seen half in "Timeseries" chart.Please check the image  [link] (http://i.stack.imgur.com/buH8J.jpg)

Comment: Try to set minPadding/maxPadding or disable startOnTick / endOnTick params.

Comment: @SebastianBochan this doesn't solve my problem. Any other solution?

Comment: Please recreate example as live demo.